# Android KeyChain: react on changes

Tags: android, keychain, android-broadcast

I am using the Android [`KeyChain`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) to store a private key / certificates from within an app.

Now if the user (for whatever reasons) removes the entry in the KeyChain manually from within the system preferences the app should act upon that event.

I successfully managed to get the respective broadcast  `ACTION_KEYCHAIN_CHANGED` when the entry in the KeyChain I generated is removed.

However I do not know how to check programmatically if the broadcast was really caused by removal of my entry in the KeyChain or the removal of some other entry. Of course I only want the app to react IFF it was really "its" entry.

Does anyone how to check if a specific entry in the KeyChain (e.g. with alias="xyz") still exists?

**EDIT 1:**
I have already tried to check if the alias still exists by doing the following but could not find it there. It tried type "AndroidCAStore" (containing all system and user CA certificates but nothing from KeyChain) and type "AndroidKeyStore" (no entries)

Maybe I have to use another type of Keystore?

```
val ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore")
ks.load(null, null)
val containsAlias = ks.containsAlias("alias_of_the_entry_in_KeyChain")
```

**EDIT 2:**
OK, at least according to [this Samsung Knox website](http://www.google.de):

> User applications accessing the Android Keystore directly do not have access to credentials stored by the Android KeyChain, and therefore, must use the Android KeyChain API to access those credentials.

However, I did not find any way to check if an entry / alias exists in the KeyChain via the KeyChain API.

Comment: `KeyChain` API uses KeyStore System so i think `keyStore.containsAlias(aliasName)` should work . Give it a try .

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I have tried this, but maybe I am using the wrong type of an instance of the Keystore.
At least with type "AndroidCAStore" I could not find the entry I stored in the KeyChain.